# How to implement an interface to limit getting and setting properties of class

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

I am struggling with understanding C# `interface`s.  I understand that they allow for multiple inheritance.  I'm trying to code for a scenario: Employees can view their own data, but not others.  Managers can view and edit Employee information, if the Employee reports to that Manager.

So I start with an abstract class, since everyone is a User and takes vacation the same.

```
public abstract class User {
    string _id;
    string _firstName;
    string _lastName;
    double _salaryAmount;
    double _bonusAmount;
    int _vacationBalance;

    public void TakeVacation(int hours) {
        _vacationBalance -= hours;
    }

    //do I implement this here?
    /*
    public int SalaryAmount{ }
    */
}
```

Should I use an interface to define `IEditable` and `IViewable`?
Could I do something like this?

```
public interface IEditable {

    double SalaryAmount { get; set; }

}

public class Employee : User, IEditable {

    public double SalaryAmount {
        get {
            return base._salaryAmount;
        }
        set {
            base._salaryAmount = value;
        }
    }
}

//Will I need a ReadOnlyEmployee or something?
```

I'm just not sure how to block a Manager from editing a User, or how to write an interface for this type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd say that Interfaces allow multiple inheritance (not in the true C++ form).  An interface provides an abstraction which allows multiple implementations to behave consistently via a predefined set of methods/properties.

Often this is used as a general abstraction, for example say you want to get some data.  You can create an Interface that surfaces a method that returns a Stream.  Then based on the implementation of the object you can return the stream from a file or websocket or pipe, etc. without the consumer of the interface knowing/caring where it's coming from.

In your example you don't have to do anything in the User class, because it doesn't implement the IEditable interface, only the Employee class does.

Here's what I think you are looking for.  This uses Explicit interface syntax (IEditable.Name) because the base method name and the interface name are the same but need to act differently.

```
public abstract class User {
    public String Id { get; protected set; }
    public String FirstName { get; protected set; }
    public String LastName { get; protected set; }
    // ...
    public Double SalaryAmount { get; protected set; }
    // ...
    public Int32 VacationBalance { get; protected set; }

    public void TakeVacation(int hours) {
        VacationBalance -= hours;
        }
    }

public interface IEditable {
    Double SalaryAmount { get; set; }
    }

public class Employee: User, IEditable {
    #region IEditable Members
    double IEditable.SalaryAmount {
        get { return base.SalaryAmount; }
        set { base.SalaryAmount = value; }
        }
    #endregion
    }


class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var emp = new Employee();
        emp.SalaryAmount = 3; // ERROR!
        ((IEditable) emp).SalaryAmount = 3; // GOOD!
        }
    }
```

Comment: So how could I limit the casting of an Employee to an IEditable to only managers who manage that employee?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that using a class system.  The knowledge of who manages whom is external to the code.  You can control implicit/explicit casting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx) so you can look up at run and return a null interface if whatever condition you set isn't met.